# Oracle Bulk Binding Row count

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

While inserting/updating million of records into a database table, how do I came to know how many records has been inserted or updated successfully so far?

Answer (score 1):

SQL%ROWCOUNT is what you're searching for.

REF: [Implicit cursors attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm)

Comment: I am not sure this answers his question. Sql%rowcount returns the number of records RIGHT AFTER the execution of a query.  It is not a means of knowing how many records have been  updated by a long running update statement that is still running..  And this seems to be the point of his question.

Comment: You  could be right... if it was the case, the right place is the view V$SESSION_LONGOPS

Answer (score 0):

yes  you can use SQL%ROWCOUNT ,In the other way you can also use cnt variable.intialyze it and increase the counter varibale inside your loop and print it.